# How can I deploy static files to IIS using Jenkins?

Tags: iis, jenkins, iis-7, continuous-integration

I currently have an application that is being successfully built in Jenkins.

My staging environment is IIS7. After a successful build I want to delete the files that are in the IIS directory and then copy the files from the latest successful build to the folder. Essentially deploying the latest successful build to IIS.

Any guidance would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Take a look at this answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5582095/deploying-net-with-jenkins-hudson